# Can't port forward from HG8245H

Tags: port-forwarding, minecraft

I was going to play Minecraft with friends, so I decided to host the server. Creating it was easy, but connecting to it remotely not. I had to watch many tutorials on how to do this, yet the port 25565 won't open, even after restarting the PC and the router itself.

### What I've tried:

- Creating inbound/outbound rules to allow access to the 25565 port.
- Turning off Windows Security (if that helps)
- Setting a static private IP address
- Allowing Java to go through the firewall

### Specifications:

- Router: Huawei - HG8245H
- Connection: Lan (4)

### More on detail:

**Port forwarding**

I added a port mapping configuration which establishes what port (25565) could be accessed. My private and external IP.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOZmm.png

**Firewall rules**

I created firewall rules which allow the port 25565 to be accessed, this applies to inbound and outbound rules and uses both protocols (UDP & TCP)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBcUN.png

**Other**

- I turned off all Windows Security protection settings.
- I set a private static IP.
- And I allowed Java instances through the firewall.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1RMI.png

**Minecraft details**

- In the server.properties file the specified port is specified which I open in all possible ways. Also, a demonstration that the server horks but only on localhost (0), but no in remote mode (***.***.***.***:25565)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQaG2.jpg

**Port checking attempts**

After restarting my PC and router after all the changes made I tried again to check if the port 25565 was open (several websites) but it was not, this are the results.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTJuQ.png

Comment: Sometimes ISPs will use CGNAT (Carrier-Grade NAT) to assign multiple customers one external IP. If your ISP does this, it's impossible for you to open a port to the internet. For more information, what are the first two octets (i.e. the A and B from A.B.C.D) of your external IP as shown in your router's configuration page?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that in other computers of my local network they had the same external IP, that's why I can't port forward? How I solve this, please tell me. Nevertheless, I can't tell you my two octets, you know because of hackers.

Comment: Well, that's actually why I only asked for the first two octets, you know, because that would mean I only have a 1/64,536 chance of guessing your IP :) if it starts with 192, 172, or 10, you're under a CGNAT. Unless it's 172. In that case you're under CGNAT if the second octet is between 16 and 32.

Comment: it is none of the numbers you mentioned, so... I will use NGrok it seems promising if you can give a suggestion also, it would be appreciated.

Comment: That's the external IP as listed in your router config page or the one you get when you Google "what's my IP"? You shouldn't need to use anything other than regular port forwarding if it's the one in the router config page.

Comment: Is the google one, but ipv4 https://myexternalip.com/ Ps: I do know about networking but not that much.

Comment: Also, I see you have something blacked out on external source IP. That should be 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255, or something like that, to signify that you wish to accept traffic from all IP addresses to your opened port.